"I used to live with my family, but now I'm living alone with my girlfriend." Do native speakers use "alone" this way?
I've heard:


She's a single mom living alone with her young son.


But what about?


I used to live with my family, but now I'm living alone with my girlfriend.


These two situations are a bit different because in the first sentence, alone means not with her partner. In the second sentence, however, I'm living with my girlfriend, so I'm not sure if it's still correct.

No, "alone" does not mean "no longer with my parents" or "out on my own for the first time".  The single mom is different, in that there it is used loosely to mean "without a spouse or partner" i.e. "on her own" emotionally and financially.

I think it's partly due to the age of the child. "She's living alone with her baby" sounds more natural than "She's living alone with a lodger" or "She's living alone with her adult son".  Although there may be situations where it's valid to use alone when another adult is there. Something like "she feels alone living with her family" is also fine. But "live alone" defines specific living arrangements: it's a little harder to say precisely what they are.

"Living alone with my girlfriend" sounds odd for the simple fact that "alone" means by yourself, not with another person. You can't be alone and with somebody.
However, "living with [my] family" is often an idiomatic way to refer to living with one's parents. Even people who are married with kids (ie they have a family of their own) may refer back to the time when they 'lived with their family'. If you think that such a statement could cause confusion then you'd be more specific, for example "I used to live with my parents, but now I'm living with my girlfriend".
"Single mom" is different. That is a compound noun that idiomatically means a lone parent - someone raising children without a partner. Also, "single" usually refers to one's relationship/marital status, so you can be single and still live with other people, be that with your children, or other adults with whom you have a platonic relationship (such as a friend, housemate) or even business relationship (such as a lodger).
